# Giving permissions on SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, permissions, user-roles

I am in the process of configuring database users for some new developers and I am running into some difficulties as I am reading lots of articles and it's not working out too well for me. I have tried various configurations manually and with T-SQL but I need a more efficient method.

**My objective:**

Some TSQL I can launch to give a database user the following permissions:

- Grant permission to execute all Stored Procedures within the Database
- Deny permission to View Definition of all of these stored procedures
- Grant permission to SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE from all tables within the database
- Deny permission to View Definition of all of the tables in the database (I don't want them to view the data)

**What I have tried:**

I have achieved this manually but I have 200+ stored procedures and 100+ tables so I don't want to do it manually.  From the T-SQL aspect I have managed to get the following to work:

```
USE database_name;
GRANT EXECUTE TO [security_account];
```

This works and allows the users to run the stored procedures but they cannot view the actual query code. I need the same logic for the tables as described above.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: When you say you don't want them to view the data, do you mean you don't want them to view the schema? Otherwise granting them `select` makes very little sense.

Comment: @TZHX I hadn't actually thought about that. Is there any way to let a stored procedure SELECT but stop the user? I hadn't thought that they could just write their own queries in the application and select all of the data they want

Comment: If a user has permission to exec a sproc, then anything in that sproc will run but doesn't mean a user has permission to do it (those actions performed by the sproc) outside of the sproc.

Comment: @TZHX I found a way to resolve this problem. I allow the users to execute the storeds but I execute the stored procedures as a different user who has permission to select/update etc. This is because the stored procedures are dynamic. What do you think of this solution?

Comment: If you just want to change permissions for all tables then the not too well documented and known sys procedure sp_MSforeachtable might to the trick: exec sp_MSforeachtable 'grant select, insert, update, delete on ? to public; '

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if this is a viable solution to your problem. But maybe it will get you at least closer to what you want. So, here is the setup I'd propose:

1. Do not grant anybody any permissions on any table.
2. Use stored procedures for DML.
3. Grant execute on all these stored procedures to public.
4. Setup one table in your database which lists all users which have access to your database including their login (suser_sname()) and their permissions (for example MayAlterTableUsers).
5. Implement into all stored procedures a check similar to this

> ```
> if (
>     select  isnull(MayAlterTableUsers, 0)
>     from    tblUsers
>     where   LoginName = suser_sname()
>    ) > 0
>     begin
>         select  N'Implementing the requested changes to tblUsers.'
>     end
> else
>     begin
>         select  N'You don''t have the required permission.'
>     end
> ```

6. Setup you views similar and grant select on all views to public

> ```
> create view vShowAllUsers as
>     select  *
>     from    dbo.tblUsers
>     cross apply (
>                  select MaySeeAllUsers
>                  from   dbo.tblUsers
>                  where  LoginName = suser_sname()
>                 ) as p
>     where   p.MaySeeAllUsers = 1
> ```

In the end all views and all stored procedures will be publicly available but the handling of permission will be within each one of them. All permissions themselves will be within this table tblUsers. Since nobody has the possibility to alter this table tblUsers unless (of course) they are in this table with the appropriate permission, this DB setup is self-contained.